# Relational MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, relational

I have a table named "prices" in which I have two fields where I reference two other tables named "prodcuts" and "supliers". In the "prices" table I do reference to the "id" of the "prodcuts" and "supliers" and I need to get the name of both in a php code... What I have so far is this, but I don't know how to make it work:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM prices") or die("Could not find");

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     while ($rr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
         $a = $rr['id'];
         $b = $rr['date'];
         $c = $rr['product'];
         $d = $rr['suplier'];
         $e = $rr['quantity'];
         $f = $rr['packaging'];
         $g = $rr['event'];
         $h = $rr['price'];

         $prov .="
               <tr>                                  
                 <td>".$b."</td>
                 <td><a href='productos-result.php?search=".$c."'>".$c."</a></td>
                 <td><a href='proveedores-result.php?search=".$d."'>".$d."</a></td>
                 <td>".$e."</td>
                 <td>".$g."</td>
                 <td>$".$h."</td>    
               </tr>";
        }
}
```

I need to display the name of the product $c and suplier $d instead of the id, my tables are like this:

## prices

id, date, productid, suplierid, quantity, event, price

## product

id, name, description

## suplier

id, name, description

Comment: Join the `prices` table with `product` and `supplier`.

Comment: If that doesn't mean anything to you, you need to read a SQL tutorial on joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to join the products and suppliers and have their names in the list of columns aliased to what you want.

```
SELECT prices.id,
       prices.date,
       product.name product,
       suplier.name suplier,
       prices.quantity,
       prices.packaging,
       prices.event,
       prices.price
       FROM prices
            INNER JOIN product
                       ON product.id = prices.productid
            INNER JOIN suplier
                       ON suplier.id = prices.suplierid;
```

(Change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` if you have prices without supplier or product but want to show them anyway (with empty names).)